Why isn't "\n" interpreted as newline character when a String like, "abc\nabc" is given as input via Scanner class in Java?
In Java, when we try to print a Hardcoded String like, "abc\nabc", we observe a line change after the first abc but when we take same input via sc.next() or sc.nextLine() it prints out '\n' as the part of string itself without any line change.
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = "abc\nabc";
        String s2 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}


Input:

abc\nabc

Output:

 abc
 abc
 abc\nabc

Shouldn't the input String also have a line change when printed back?

That \n and other "escaped characters" have special meanings to the compiler does not necessarily mean they have those same meanings in other situations.

Or to put it another way ... Scanner (and the Java runtime libraries in general) don't understand Java source code syntax.  Specifically character and string literal escape syntax.  When your program reads the characters '' and 'n' from some stream, they just stand for themselves.  Two distinct characters.  Not an ASCII / Unicode NL (newline) character / codepoint.

(Interestingly, Pattern is a kind of exception to this.  But it understands a >>different<< backslash escaping syntax. In a regex you can escape any character with a backslash.  And then you have the issue that when a regex is represented in Java source code as a string literal, the escapes must be escaped!!)

The reason "\n" in a Java string literal is a line feed character is because the compiler interprets it as such. It sees a '' character (ASCII 98) followed by an 'n' character (ASCII 110) and replaces that sequence with a line feed character (ASCII 10) during compilation (i.e., the escape sequence has meaning at compile-time but not run-time). The Scanner class is not defined to do that, so any "\n" it sees in the text it reads is left alone. That's not to say a class couldn't be written so that it does replace "\n" with a line feed.

Typing \n into a console does not constitute entering new line. The Enter key does that. Typing \n constitutes entering a backslash and then an n.

Related: How to read “\n” text in file as a newline?

When you have \n in a string literal in your source code, it is a character escape, and the compiler translates that to the new line character when it produces the value of the string. Given the \ introduces escapes, if you want a \ in a string literal, you need to use its escape \\.
However, a \n in a string value, like when you type \n in the console, or in a text file, that is just two characters: the \ and n, and they have no special meaning. You need to replace them yourself, or use an unescaper like org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String) from Apache Commons Text to get the same behaviour as the compiler produces when interpreting literals in your source code
